# Real-Time Copying and Pasting to Excel

Tags: python, excel, copy, openpyxl, pyperclip

I made this simple program using openpyxl and pyperclip that pastes the clipboard's contents on to successive rows in Excel - so for instance if I copied the word 'hello', it will paste 'hello' on to the cells 'A2, A3, A4...'

However, my main goal is to create a program where I can copy text in real-time and the program pastes it to the cells as so. For example, I copy the text 'hello', the program pastes it onto A2, then I copy the text 'I like python' and it pastes that onto to cell A3 and so on(and then I press a key to end the program when I am done).

Is this possible? If so how can I do this? (I am open to downloading new libraries etc.)

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pyperclip

wb = Workbook()

column = 'A'
row = 0

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

#loop through excel rows
for x in range(2,6):
   row = x
   cell = column + str(row)
   ws[cell] = pyperclip.paste()
   
# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Additional Help: In the case, I (with your help) figure out how to do this, I will also appreciate if someone can tell me how to save the cell number/code too. So for e.g. I run the program and paste the respective text on the the cells 'A1, A2, A3...A14.' Is there a way to also save 'A14' into the memory, so the next time I run the program it starts from A14 and pastes accordingly -'A14, A15, A16...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pyperclip


wb = Workbook()

column = 'A'
row = 0

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

clipboard = ["quote", "random"]

limit = 10

recentcopy = 'a'

x = 1
while(len(clipboard)<limit):
    recentcopy = pyperclip.paste()
    if(recentcopy != clipboard [x]):
        clipboard.append(pyperclip.paste())
        print(clipboard)
        row = x + 1
        cell = column + str(row)
        ws[cell] = clipboard[x]
        wb.save("heyo.xlsx")
        x = x+1
```

Comment: This is working. I will still appreciate if someone can answer the additional question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution for storing which cell you were at, I'd recommend writing the cell to a text file, then having your program read the text file when it starts so it knows where to continue from. Tutorial for text files with python can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/